# NSLayoutConstraint has no member 'Attribute'

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to convert swift code in following

```
NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height
```

I am using `SkeletonView` which it throws me error while executing.

I was not able to find the new replacement syntax of that

Type 'NSLayoutConstraint' has no member 'Attribute'

Comment: What exactly are you trying to access? Which elements height?

Comment: What version of Xcode and what version of Swift are you using? What is your Base SDK?

Comment: @DionizB I am sorry. I just run my app and throws me this error. I also don't know what actually happening...

Comment: @rmaddy I am using Xcode 9.4 and swift 4.1. iOS version 11.0

Comment: That's the issue. `NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height` requires Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10. Use whatever version of that constant is for the version of Swift/iOS you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on the version of Swift you are using.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height // Swift 4.2

NSLayoutAttribute.height // Swift 3.0+

NSLayoutAttributeHeight // Swift 2?
```

Comment: Thank for saving my day ;)

Comment: It's actually based on the swift version you were using.In order to find the corresponding key click(⌘ + click) on the **ClassName** (eg:NSLayoutConstraint here).You will be taken to the description tab, where you can search for attribute and get the respective  names .Eg: NSLayoutConstraintAttribute for ".attribute" , UIControlState for ".stack", UIStackViewAlignment for ".alignment" not a member problems

Answer (score 1):

Your swift version might not applicable with that syntax which used in swift 4.2

I am sure that your current swift version is low than that.

So, replace that line of code with
`NSlayoutAttribute.height` which applicable for swift version 3+ but below 4.2